# Get Intel(R) Management Engine Interface version using powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to get Intel(R) Management Engine Interface version using

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -like "*Intel(R) Management Engine Interface*"}
```

But Im getting result that looks like:

```
devicename                                                  driverversion
----------                                                  -------------
Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
```

But as I check from device manager I am getting those information example:

[image]

Comment: Works fine here and Shows the driverversion in PS, but my driver (ver 11.0.0.1176) is signed in devmgmt.msc.You can try to update the driver to 11.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `select` (alias for `Select-Object`) like that, you're telling PowerShell "I want *only* these properties, remove everything else". Filter without using `select` instead:

```
$MgmtInterface = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -like "*Intel(R) Management Engine Interface*"}
```

Now, to get the information you're after, select the relevant properties:

```
$MgmtInterface |Select-Object DriverProviderName,DriverDate,DriverVersion,@{Name='Digital Signer';Expression={if($_.IsSigned){$_.Signer}else{'Not digitally signed'}}}
```

Comment: Basically that was the cause, no remote signing.